# An optional<T> implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

This is an implementation of [`optional<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) from C++17, it is mostly standard conforming.

I'm looking for a review on efficiency, correctness and performance.

#### Sample usage

```
#include "optional.h"

int main()
{
    util::optional<std::string> s0{ "abc" };
    util::optional<std::string> s1;

    if ( s1 ) s0 = s1;
    else s1 = s0;

    if ( s0 == s1 && s0 == std::string{ "abc" } )
    {
        s1 = "def";
        s0 = util::nullopt;
    }

    using std::swap;
    swap( s1, s0 );

    std::cout << *s0 << '\n';
    std::cout << s1.value_or( "default" ) << '\n';
}
```

#### Implementation

**optional.h**

```
#ifndef UTIL_OPTIONAL_H
#define UTIL_OPTIONAL_H

#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include "optional_comparison.h"

namespace util
{
    // 20.5.4, in-place construction
    struct in_place_t {};
    constexpr in_place_t in_place{};

    // 20.5.5, no-value state indicator
    struct nullopt_t
    {
        constexpr nullopt_t( int const ) noexcept {};
    };
    constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{ 0 };

    // 20.5.6, class bad_optional_access
    class bad_optional_access : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        bad_optional_access() : logic_error( "uninitialized optional" ) {}
    };

    // 20.5.3, optional for object types
    template <typename T>
    class optional
    {
    private:
        struct conversion_ctor_t {};
        static constexpr conversion_ctor_t conversion_ctor{};

    public:
        template <typename U> friend class optional;

        using value_type = T;

        // 20.5.3.2, destructor
        // issue: not trivially destructible if T is trivially destructible
        ~optional() noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            destroy_value();
        }

        // 20.5.3.1, constructors
        // issue: vc++2015 update 2 cannot declare the following as constexpr:
        //      optional();
        //      optional( nullopt_t );
        //      optional( optional const& );
        //      optional( optional&& );
        //      optional( T const& );
        //      optional( T&& );
        constexpr optional() noexcept : m_has_value{ false } {}
        constexpr optional( nullopt_t ) noexcept : m_has_value{ false } {}

        constexpr optional( optional const& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value )
            : m_has_value{ other.m_has_value }
        {
            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                emplace( other.m_value );
            }
        }

        constexpr optional( optional&& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value )
            : m_has_value{ other.m_has_value }
        {
            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                emplace( std::move( other.m_value ) );
            }
        }

        constexpr optional( T const& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value )
            : optional( in_place, value )
        {}

        constexpr optional( T&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value )
            : optional( in_place, std::move( value ) )
        {}

        template <typename... Args>
        constexpr optional( in_place_t, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value )
            : m_has_value{ true }
            , m_value( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}

        template
        <
            typename U,
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t
            <
                std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value, int
            > = 0
        >
        constexpr optional( in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<U,
                std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value )
            : m_has_value{ true }
            , m_value( il, std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}

        // 20.5.3.3, assignment
        optional& operator=( nullopt_t )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            destroy_value();
            m_has_value = false;
            return *this;
        }

        optional& operator=( optional const& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value )
        {
            if ( static_cast<void*>( this ) != &other )
            {
                if ( other.m_has_value )
                {
                    set_value( other.m_value );
                }
                else
                {
                    destroy_value();
                    m_has_value = false;
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        optional& operator=( optional&& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value )
        {
            if ( static_cast<void*>( this ) != &other )
            {
                if ( other.m_has_value )
                {
                    set_value( std::move( other.m_value ) );
                }
                else
                {
                    destroy_value();
                    m_has_value = false;
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        template
        <
            typename U,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>, T>::value, int> = 0
        >
        optional& operator=( U&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_assignable<T, U&&>::value )
        {
            set_value( std::forward<U>( value ) );
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename... Args>
        void emplace( Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value )
        {
            *this = nullopt;
            ::new ( &m_value ) T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
            m_has_value = true;
        }

        template
        <
            typename U,
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t
            <
                std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value, int
            > = 0
        >
        void emplace( std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T,
                std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value )
        {
            *this = nullopt;
            ::new ( &m_value ) T( il, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
            m_has_value = true;
        }

        // 20.5.3.4, swap
    void swap( optional& other )
        noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
            noexcept( std::swap( std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>() ) ) )
    {
        if ( this != &other )
        {
            if ( m_has_value && other.m_has_value )
            {
                using std::swap;
                swap( m_value, other.m_value );
            }
            else if ( m_has_value )
            {
                other.m_has_value = true;
                other.emplace( std::move( m_value ) );
                destroy_value();
                m_has_value = false;
            }
            else if ( other.m_has_value )
            {
                m_has_value = true;
                emplace( std::move( other.m_value ) );
                other.destroy_value();
                other.m_has_value = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // 20.5.3.5, observers
    // issue 1: vc++2015 update 2 cannot declare the following as constexpr:
    //      T* operator->() noexcept;
    //      T const* operator->() const noexcept;
    //      T& operator*() & noexcept;
    //      T const& operator*() const & noexcept;
    //      T&& operator*() && noexcept;
    //      T const&& operator*() const && noexcept;
    // issue 2: issue 1 + cannot be implemented as single line return statement
    //      T& value() &;
    //      T const& value() const &;
    //      T&& value() &&;
    //      T const&& value() const &&;
    constexpr T* operator->() noexcept { return &m_value; }
    constexpr T const* operator->() const noexcept { return &m_value; }

    constexpr T& operator*() & noexcept { return m_value; }
    constexpr T const& operator*() const & noexcept { return m_value; }

    constexpr T&& operator*() && noexcept { return m_value; }
    constexpr T const&& operator*() const && noexcept { return m_value; }

    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return m_has_value; }

    constexpr T& value() &
    {
        if ( m_has_value ) return m_value;
        throw bad_optional_access{};
    }

    constexpr T const& value() const&
    {
        if ( m_has_value ) return m_value;
        throw bad_optional_access{};
    }

    constexpr T&& value() &&
    {
        if ( m_has_value ) return std::move( m_value );
        throw bad_optional_access{};
    }

    constexpr T const&& value() const&&
    {
        if ( m_has_value ) return std::move( m_value );
        throw bad_optional_access{};
    }

    template <typename U>
    constexpr auto value_or( U&& default_value ) const &
        noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
            std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U&&>::value )
    {
        return m_has_value ?
            m_value : static_cast<T>( std::forward<U>( default_value ) );
    }

    template <typename U>
    constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value ) &&
        noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
            std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U&&>::value )
    {
        return m_has_value ?
            std::move( m_value ) : static_cast<T>( std::forward<U>( default_value ) );
    }

    private:
        template <typename U>
        auto set_value( U&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, decltype( value )>::value )
        -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, decltype( value )>::value>
        {
            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                m_value = std::forward<U>( value );
            }
            else
            {
                m_has_value = true;
                emplace( std::forward<U>( value ) );
            }
        }

        constexpr void destroy_value()
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            if ( !std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value && m_has_value )
            {
                m_value.T::~T();
            }
        }

        bool m_has_value;
        union
        {
            T m_value;
        };
    };

    // 20.5.10, specialized algorithms - swap
    template <typename T>
    void swap( optional<T>& lhs, optional<T>& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( lhs.swap( rhs ) ) )
    {
        lhs.swap( rhs );
    }

    // 20.5.10, specialized algorithms - make_optional
    template <typename T>
    optional<std::decay_t<T>> make_optional( T&& value )
        noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, decltype( value )>::value )
    {
        return optional<std::decay_t<T>>{ std::forward<T>( value ) };
    }
}

namespace std
{
    // 20.5.11, hash support
    template <typename T>
    struct hash<util::optional<T>>
    {
        auto operator()( util::optional<T> const& value ) const
        {
            static hash<T> hasher;
            return hasher( *value );
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

**optional_comparison.h**

```
#ifndef UTIL_OPTIONAL_COMPARISON_H
#define UTIL_OPTIONAL_COMPARISON_H
namespace util
{
    // 20.5.5, no-value state indicator
    struct nullopt_t;

    // 20.5.3, optional for object types
    template <typename T> class optional;

    // 20.5.7, relational operators
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( *lhs == *rhs ) )
    {
        /* function code is equivalent to:
        if ( static_cast<bool>( lhs ) != static_cast<bool>( rhs ) )
            return false;
        else if ( !lhs )
            return true;
        else
            return *lhs == *rhs;
        */
        // vc++2015 update 2 constexpr compliant
        return static_cast<bool>( lhs ) != static_cast<bool>( rhs ) ?
            false : !lhs ? true : *lhs == *rhs;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator==( lhs, rhs ) ) )
    {
        return !operator==( lhs, rhs );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( *lhs < *rhs ) )
    {
        /* function code is equivalent to:
        if ( !rhs )
            return false;
        else if ( !lhs )
            return true;
        else
            return *lhs < *rhs;
        */
        // vc++2015 update 2 constexpr compliant
        return !rhs ? false : !lhs ? true : *lhs < *rhs;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( lhs, rhs ) ) )
    {
        return operator<( rhs, lhs );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator>( lhs, rhs ) ) )
    {
        return !operator<( rhs, lhs );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=( optional<T> const& lhs, optional<T> const& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( lhs, rhs ) ) )
    {
        return !operator<( lhs, rhs );
    }

    // 20.5.8, comparison with nullopt
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return !opt;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return !opt;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>( opt );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>( opt );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>( opt );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return !opt;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return static_cast<bool>( opt );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=( optional<T> const& opt, nullopt_t ) noexcept
    {
        return true;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=( nullopt_t, optional<T> const& opt ) noexcept
    {
        return !opt;
    }

    // 20.5.9, comparison with T
    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( *opt == value ) )
    {
        return opt ? *opt == value : false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator==( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator==( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return operator==( opt, value );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator==( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return !operator==( opt, value );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator!=( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator==( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return !operator==( opt, value );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( *opt < value ) )
    {
        return opt ? *opt < value : true;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return opt ? value < *opt : false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator>( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return !operator>( opt, value );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator<=( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator>( value, opt ) ) )
    {
        return !operator>( value, opt );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( value, opt ) ) )
    {
        return opt ? value < *opt : false;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return opt ? *opt < value : true;
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=( optional<T> const& opt, T const& value )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( opt, value ) ) )
    {
        return !operator<( opt, value );
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool operator>=( T const& value, optional<T> const& opt )
        noexcept( noexcept( operator<( value, opt ) ) )
    {
        return !operator<( value, opt );
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Bugs

Consider this:

```
T val;
optional<T> o;
o = val;
```

This calls `operator=(U&& value)` with `U = T&`, which calls `set_value(U&& value)` with `U = T&`, which sets `m_has_value` to `true` *then* calls `emplace()`! This makes `emplace()` think that you actually have a value, and so destroys it. But we didn't have a value originally - so undefined behavior.

You have similar bugs in other places. `emplace()` is responsible for setting `m_has_value()` to true, nothing else.

In a similar vein, `destroy_value()` should set `m_has_value` to `false`, so that you don't have to manually do it in other places.

---

#### Constructors

This constructor needs SFINAE:

```
template <typename... Args>
constexpr optional( in_place_t, Args&&... args )
```

Otherwise you'll get the wrong thing from `is_constructible`.

This constructor seems wrong - what types are constructible from both an `initializer_list` and something else (I'm omitting the SFINAE for brevity)? Perhaps just the `initializer_list`?

```
template<typename U, typename... Args>
constexpr optional( in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args )
```

#### Assignment

This cast is unnecessary:

```
if ( static_cast<void*>( this ) != &other )
```

#### Destructor

You don't have to check if `is_trivially_destructible<T>::value`. If it were trivially destructible, the destructor just wouldn't do anything. So you can just write:

```
constexpr void destroy_value() noexcept(std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value)
{
    if (m_has_value) {
        m_value.T::~T();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bugs: Thanks for pointing these out. Constructors: (1) The standard does not say that the first `in_place_t` constructor should be removed from overload resolution. If that's not what you meant, please tell clarify. (2) This constructor is required by the standard; example use: `optional<vector<int>> ov{ in_place, { 1, 2, 3 }, myalloc<int>{} }`.

Comment: But yes, that constructor is weird; it's the first of its kind that I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

#### 20.5.3.2, destructor - making it trivial

The standard indicates that if `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value == true`, then `optional<T>` must be trivially destructible.

In order to achieve this, the uninitialized storage cannot be in an union, as that causes `optional<T>`'s destructor be declared as deleted.

Here's the type to do just that:

```
#ifndef UTIL_MAYBE_TRIVIALLY_DESTRUCTIBLE_STORAGE_H
#define UTIL_MAYBE_TRIVIALLY_DESTRUCTIBLE_STORAGE_H

#include <new>
#include <type_traits>

namespace util
{
    template <typename T>
    struct maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base
    {
        explicit maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base( bool const has_value )
            : m_has_value{ has_value }
        {}

        template
        <
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value, int> = 0
        >
        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base( Args&&... args )
            : m_has_value{ true }
        {
            ::new ( &m_data ) T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
        }

        //  issue : vc++2015 update 2 cannot declare the following as constexpr
        //      T& value() & noexcept;
        //      T const& value() const & noexcept;
        constexpr T& value() & noexcept
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<T&>( m_data );
        }

        constexpr T const& value() const & noexcept
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<T const&>( m_data );
        }

        bool m_has_value;
        std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof( T ), alignof( T )> m_data;
    };

    template
    <
        typename T,
        bool is_trivially_destructible = std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value
    >
    struct maybe_trivially_destructible_storage
        : public maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>
    {
        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage( bool const has_value )
            : maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>( has_value )
        {}

        template
        <
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value, int> = 0
        >
        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage( Args&&... args )
            : maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct maybe_trivially_destructible_storage<T, false>
        : public maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>
    {
        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage( bool const has_value )
            : maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>( has_value )
        {}

        template
        <
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value, int> = 0
        >
        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage( Args&&... args )
            : maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}

        ~maybe_trivially_destructible_storage()
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            if ( maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>::m_has_value )
            {
                maybe_trivially_destructible_storage_base<T>::value().T::~T();
            }
        };
    };
}
#endif
```

By using this new type, `optional<T>` is now trivially destructible if `T` is trivially destructible.

#### Using the new storage type and bug fixes

This is the full implementation of `optional<T>` using the new storage type and taking into account what [Barry's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/127533/88422) points out. The comparison operators stay the same.

```
#ifndef UTIL_OPTIONAL_H
#define UTIL_OPTIONAL_H

#include <new>
#include <type_traits>
#include "maybe_trivially_destructible_storage.h"
#include "optional_comparison.h"

namespace util
{
    // 20.5.4, in-place construction
    struct in_place_t {};
    constexpr in_place_t in_place{};

    // 20.5.5, no-value state indicator
    struct nullopt_t
    {
        constexpr nullopt_t( int const ) noexcept {};
    };
    constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{ 0 };

    // 20.5.6, class bad_optional_access
    class bad_optional_access : public std::logic_error
    {
    public:
        bad_optional_access() : logic_error( "uninitialized optional" ) {}
    };

    // 20.5.3, optional for object types
    template <typename T>
    class optional
    {
    public:
        template <typename U> friend class optional;

        using value_type = T;

        // 20.5.3.2, destructor
        ~optional() = default;

        // 20.5.3.1, constructors
        // issue: vc++2015 update 2 cannot declare the following as constexpr:
        //      optional();
        //      optional( nullopt_t );
        //      optional( optional const& );
        //      optional( optional&& );
        //      optional( T const& );
        //      optional( T&& );
        constexpr optional() noexcept : m_storage{ false } {}
        constexpr optional( nullopt_t ) noexcept : m_storage{ false } {}

        constexpr optional( optional const& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value )
            : m_storage{ other.m_storage.m_has_value }
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value )
            {
                emplace( other.m_storage.value() );
            }
        }

        constexpr optional( optional&& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value )
            : m_storage( other.m_storage.m_has_value )
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value )
            {
                emplace( std::move( other.m_storage.value() ) );
            }
        }

        constexpr optional( T const& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value )
            : optional( in_place, value )
        {}

        constexpr optional( T&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value )
            : optional( in_place, std::move( value ) )
        {}

        template <typename... Args>
        constexpr optional( in_place_t, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value )
            : m_storage( std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}

        template
        <
            typename U,
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t
            <
                std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value,
                int
            > = 0
        >
        constexpr optional( in_place_t, std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<U,
                std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value )
            : m_storage( il, std::forward<Args>( args )... )
        {}

        // 20.5.3.3, assignment
        optional& operator=( nullopt_t )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            destroy_value();
            return *this;
        }

        optional& operator=( optional const& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable<T>::value )
        {
            if ( this != &other )
            {
                if ( other.m_storage.m_has_value )
                {
                    set_value( other.m_storage.value() );
                }
                else
                {
                    destroy_value();
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        optional& operator=( optional&& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_move_assignable<T>::value )
        {
            if ( this != &other )
            {
                if ( other.m_storage.m_has_value )
                {
                    set_value( std::move( other.m_storage.value() ) );
                }
                else
                {
                    destroy_value();
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }

        template
        <
            typename U,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<U>, T>::value, int> = 0
        >
        optional& operator=( U&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_assignable<T, U&&>::value )
        {
            set_value( std::forward<U>( value ) );
            return *this;
        }

        template <typename... Args>
        void emplace( Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, Args&&...>::value )
        {
            *this = nullopt;
            ::new ( &m_storage.m_data ) T( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
            m_storage.m_has_value = true;
        }

        template
        <
            typename U,
            typename... Args,
            std::enable_if_t
            <
                std::is_constructible<T, std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value,
                int
            > = 0
        >
        void emplace( std::initializer_list<U> il, Args&&... args )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T,
                std::initializer_list<U>&, Args&&...>::value )
        {
            *this = nullopt;
            ::new ( &m_storage.m_data ) T( il, std::forward<Args>( args )... );
            m_storage.m_has_value = true;
        }

        // 20.5.3.4, swap
        void swap( optional& other )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                noexcept( std::swap( std::declval<T&>(), std::declval<T&>() ) ) )
        {
            if ( this != &other )
            {
                if ( m_storage.m_has_value && other.m_storage.m_has_value )
                {
                    using std::swap;
                    swap( m_storage.value(), other.m_storage.value() );
                }
                else if ( m_storage.m_has_value )
                {
                    other.emplace( std::move( m_storage.value() ) );
                    destroy_value();
                }
                else if ( other.m_storage.m_has_value )
                {
                    emplace( std::move( other.m_storage.value() ) );
                    other.destroy_value();
                }
            }
        }

        // 20.5.3.5, observers
        // issue 1: vc++2015 update 2 cannot declare the following as constexpr:
        //      T* operator->() noexcept;
        //      T const* operator->() const noexcept;
        //      T& operator*() & noexcept;
        //      T const& operator*() const & noexcept;
        //      T&& operator*() && noexcept;
        //      T const&& operator*() const && noexcept;
        // issue 2: issue 1 + cannot be implemented as single line return statement
        //      T& value() &;
        //      T const& value() const &;
        //      T&& value() &&;
        //      T const&& value() const &&;
        constexpr T* operator->() noexcept { return &m_storage.value(); }
        constexpr T const* operator->() const noexcept
        { return &m_storage.value(); }

        constexpr T& operator*() & noexcept { return m_storage.value(); }
        constexpr T const& operator*() const & noexcept
        { return m_storage.value(); }

        constexpr T&& operator*() && noexcept { return m_storage.value(); }
        constexpr T const&& operator*() const && noexcept
        { return m_storage.value(); }

        constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept
        { return m_storage.m_has_value; }

        constexpr T& value() &
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value ) return m_storage.value();
            throw bad_optional_access{};
        }

        constexpr T const& value() const&
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value ) return m_storage.value();
            throw bad_optional_access{};
        }

        constexpr T&& value() &&
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value ) return std::move( m_storage.value() );
            throw bad_optional_access{};
        }

        constexpr T const&& value() const&&
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value ) return std::move( m_storage.value() );
            throw bad_optional_access{};
        }

        template <typename U>
        constexpr auto value_or( U&& default_value ) const &
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U&&>::value )
        {
            return m_storage.m_has_value ?
                m_storage.value() : static_cast<T>( std::forward<U>( default_value ) );
        }

        template <typename U>
        constexpr T value_or( U&& default_value ) &&
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<T>::value &&
                std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U&&>::value )
        {
            return m_storage.m_has_value ?
                std::move( m_storage.value() ) :
                static_cast<T>( std::forward<U>( default_value ) );
        }

    private:
        template <typename U>
        void set_value( U&& value )
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, decltype( value )>::value )
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value )
            {
                m_storage.value() = std::forward<U>( value );
            }
            else
            {
                emplace( std::forward<U>( value ) );
            }
        }

        void destroy_value()
            noexcept( std::is_nothrow_destructible<T>::value )
        {
            if ( m_storage.m_has_value )
            {
                m_storage.value().T::~T();
                m_storage.m_has_value = false;
            }
        }

        maybe_trivially_destructible_storage<T> m_storage;
    };

    // 20.5.10, specialized algorithms - swap
    template <typename T>
    void swap( optional<T>& lhs, optional<T>& rhs )
        noexcept( noexcept( lhs.swap( rhs ) ) )
    {
        lhs.swap( rhs );
    }

    // 20.5.10, specialized algorithms - make_optional
    template <typename T>
    optional<std::decay_t<T>> make_optional( T&& value )
        noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, decltype( value )>::value )
    {
        return optional<std::decay_t<T>>{ std::forward<T>( value ) };
    }
}

namespace std
{
    // 20.5.11, hash support
    template <typename T>
    struct hash<util::optional<T>>
    {
        auto operator()( util::optional<T> const& value ) const
        {
            static hash<T> hasher;
            return hasher( *value );
        }
    };
}
#endif
```

#### Sample usage

With all that out of the way, here's how the class can be used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "optional.h"

int main()
{
    // vc++2015 has an issue with is_trivially_destructible
    static_assert( std::is_trivially_destructible<util::optional<int>>::value, "!" );

    std::string str{ "mystr" };
    util::optional<std::string> s0;

    s0 = str;
    std::cout << *s0 << '\n';

    s0 = util::nullopt;
    std::cout << s0.value_or( "no value, here's a default" ) << '\n';
    try
    {
        s0.value();
    }
    catch ( util::bad_optional_access const& e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    util::optional<std::vector<int>> s8
    {
        util::in_place, // constructed in place
        { 1, 2, 3 }, // initializer list
        std::allocator<int>{} // allocator
    };
    for ( auto i : *s8 )
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```